# Assign ViewBag value to input checkbox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, checkbox, viewbag

I am trying to assign `ViewBag` value in Boolean to an HTML Input checkbox. It is throwing the following error: `Cannot resolve symbol '<%=  ViewBag.Solicitation %>'`

```
<input id="chkSolicitation" type="checkbox" name="chkSolicitation" 
       checked="<%=  ViewBag.Solicitation %>" />
```

Comment: can you use checked="@ViewBag.Solicitation" />

Comment: No hes not using razor ..that would read @ViewBag.Solicitation :)

Comment: ViewBag.Solicitation should be assigned to the value="", checked just says if its checked or not, has nothing to do with the actual value assigned. btw checked is not checked="true/false", if checked exists then it's checked ..checked="false" will check the box !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend using this, assuming you are using Razor:

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkSolicitation", (bool)ViewBag.Solicitation)
```

If you are not using Razor, use this:

```
<%: Html.CheckBox("chkSolicitation", (bool)ViewData["Solicitation"]) %>
```